# jquery ajax memory leak

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

I am definitely not the first person to have a jQuery memory leak issue, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for the many questions similar to this one that I looked at.

First, the leaky bit:

```
$(document).ready(function ivr_grabber(){
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: '/ivr/inprogress',
    timeout: 3000,

    success: function(data){
        $('#open-ivrs').html(data);
        data = null;
    },
    complete: function(){
        setTimeout(ivr_grabber, 3000);
    }
});
xhr = null;
});
```

The PHP code returns a table with some people who are being called by our PBX. I've commented out the .html(data) line, and it's made no difference. I've also removed setTimeout, and then put it back, no luck. I attempted to unset all the values that might be incurring this leak, but I cant figure out where it's coming from.

It appears to be leaking at a rate of about 5 KB per ajax call. Any thoughts?

Using jQuery 1.7.2 on chrome

I've been taking heap snapshots consistently, none of the above have affected the leakiness

Comment: why are you adding the ajax call to the xhr variable?

Comment: For possible later use. I've tried not having it assign to the xhr variable, and the leak is still there.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? can you recreate the issue by pulling the code in the success out of the success and running it directly multiple times?

Comment: Why do you think that there's a memory leak?

Comment: The code in success isn't the problem, it's the code in complete. And that code is just setting a timeout, and running the function again when that timeout goes off. I'll try running it outside of the ajax though.

Comment: I think there's a memory leak because I've taken heap snapshots and seen escalating memory usage. Also, users have noted that if they leave the window open for a long time, the browser freezes (runs out of memory)

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: _What_ browser? There is just no detail here.

Comment: Chrome, also, edit above.

Comment: if `data` contains just a small simple html string, that could be the cause of the memory leak due to a caching mechanism that jQuery used up until jQuery 1.9 where it was removed. Comment out that line and try it. `$('#open-ivrs').html(data);` If that stops it, the fix would be to upgrade to the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Kevin, how small a string? It's typically a table with one row, and three data items.

Comment: I'm not sure, i've never actually reproduced it myself. I've just seen it reported and supposedly "confirmed" several times.

Comment: Kevin, that did not solve the issue I'm sorry to say. It's got to be in success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the memory leak issue. It was in:

```
setTimeout();
```

I was calling a function name, which calls the function, and then sets a timeout to call the function. There were escalating timeouts piling up. In reality i needed to use an anonymous function, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    some_func();
}, 5000);
```

EDIT: This does not actually solve the tiny inherent handle accumulation that jQuery's ajax methods are prone to. I have yet to figure olut a way around this.

EDIT 2: Another issue I encountered that caused memory leaks was mounting event handlers. Redefining an event handler like so:

```
$('#something').click(function(){ do stuff });
```

will not remove old .click() handlers, I found that using .unbind('click') solved many of the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but try declaring the function ivr_grabber outside the scope of the document.ready handler. Also, why set the jqXHR object to null? This accomplishes nothing to my knowledge and perhaps interferes with the async request.

```
$(document).ready(ivr_grabber);
function ivr_grabber() {}
```

Comment: I'll try that and get back to this

Comment: No dice, memory leak still there.